# Error upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 lts to 18.04 lts

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

When I follow the instructions from [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes) and use software updater `update-manager -c`, it crashes and the alternative gtk from shell is also showing a Python error. I'm based in Canada if that means anything. How to resolve this?

```
sudo /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk 
[sudo] password for techsri: 
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:30: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcher.py:23: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit.py:33: PyGIWarning: WebKit2 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit2 as WebKit
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/bionic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 224, in main
    from .DistUpgradeController import DistUpgradeController
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .DistUpgradeQuirks import DistUpgradeQuirks
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 36, in <module>
    from janitor.plugincore.manager import PluginManager
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/janitor/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 621
    except ResolutionError,v:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 497, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 450, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/bionic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 224, in main
    from .DistUpgradeController import DistUpgradeController
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .DistUpgradeQuirks import DistUpgradeQuirks
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 36, in <module>
    from janitor.plugincore.manager import PluginManager
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-d7e7sf9p/janitor/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pkg_resources

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 621
        except ResolutionError,v:
                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the error log:

```
Tried those steps, no effect. Here's the upgrade error log.`2018-09-04 16:37:32,358 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.xenial']'
2018-09-04 16:37:32,358 INFO uname information: 'Linux techsri-Asus-GL552VW 4.4.3-040403-generic #201602251634 SMP Thu Feb 25 21:36:25 UTC 2016 x86_64'
2018-09-04 16:37:32,709 INFO apt version: '1.2.27'
2018-09-04 16:37:32,710 INFO python version: '3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
2018-09-04 16:37:32,712 INFO release-upgrader version '18.04.24' started
2018-09-04 16:37:32,777 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2018-09-04 16:37:32,915 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-llt8xeg8/bionic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-llt8xeg8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 224, in main
    from .DistUpgradeController import DistUpgradeController

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-llt8xeg8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .DistUpgradeQuirks import DistUpgradeQuirks

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-llt8xeg8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 36, in <module>
    from janitor.plugincore.manager import PluginManager

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-llt8xeg8/janitor/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pkg_resources

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 621

    except ResolutionError,v:

                          ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

2018-09-04 16:37:32,915 DEBUG running apport_crash()
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
~  

                                                        `
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please copy and paste the error into your question?

Comment: Better.  Looks like a python error.  It could be that you don't have the right version of python installed.  Do you have the `ubuntu-desktop` package installed?  Try `apt install ubuntu-desktop` and `apt install python2.7`

Comment: Those are as they should be. But not sure why the installation is using python 3.5 when python invokes python 2.7.`techsri@techsri-Asus-GL552VW:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
`

Comment: I face the same question..

Answer (score 0):

Outside of having access to the internet, your location shouldn't make any difference and the upgrade servers as they all share the load together*.

Without seeing the error, I'm just guessing, but to start with I'd check a few things (I'll include command-line commands for each):

1. Make sure you do have access to the internet
2. Make sure you have enough disk space (`df -h`).  The installer should check this, but when things break it's best to check again.
3. Do an apt automatic repair (`apt -f install`)
4. Read the upgrade error log (and maybe copy it into your question).  It's located in the folder `/var/log/dist-upgrade/`

Please update your question with the error if this hasn't worked. :)

*(unless you've specifically locked your upgrade path to a particular server, which is not easy and you'd probably know if you had done this)

Comment: Tried those steps, no effect. Here's the upgrade error log.: